# Access to parent scope from socket.io handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, socket.io

I have code as below:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.on("req1", Handler1);
});


var Handler1= function(args1)
{
   console.log(args1);
   socket.emit('resp1', {id: 21321});  <---- ERROR - Socket not defined
}
```

Any idea how to get access to socket obj in Handler1 ?? Declaring global object and assign socket to it works, but I don't know if it is a good solution? What will happen on many client's connections to server?

Comment: Is this all your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind it:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.on("req1", create_handler(socket));
});


function create_handler(socket) {
    return function (args1) { // we return the handler function that now has access to socket
        console.log(args1);
        socket.emit('resp1', {id: 21321});
    };
}
```

Or, if you don't need to reuse the handler construction you can put it all inline:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.on("req1", function (args1) {
        console.log(args1);
        socket.emit('resp1', {id: 21321});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just define the handler within your `on` setup:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {

  var Handler1= function(args1)
  {
     console.log(args1);
     socket.emit('resp1', {id: 21321});
  }

  socket.on("req1", Handler1);
});
```

Or, if `Handler1` needs to be reused elsewhere, add a `socket` parameter to it, and call it from a wrapper function:

```
var Handler1= function(socket, args1)
{
   console.log(args1);
   socket.emit('resp1', {id: 21321});
}

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  socket.on("req1", function(a) { Handler1(socket, a); } );
});
```

Comment: Oooo i totally didnt think about wrapper idea. Thanks Paul !!

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the "Handler1" function outside of the scope where the "socket" variable is defined. If you define the handler inside the "connection" handler, it will have a reference to use.

```
   io.on("connection", function(socket) {
        var Handler1 = function(args1) {
            console.log(args1);
            socket.emit('resp1', {id: 21321}); 
        }
        socket.on("req1", Handler1);
    });
```